# How to create Account while creating New Contact from the Contact lookup on Lead

Tags: lookup, new

On Lead, I have a lookup to Contact. When I attempt to create a new contact from this lookup field, the new Contact dialog box appears, but within here, I cannot create a new Account from the Account lookup field. On the other hand, when I create a new Contact from the Contacts tab, I am able to create a new Account from the Account lookup field. Is there a way I can create a new account, while creating a new Contact from the Contact lookup field ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are on classic because right now it is unavailable to disable quick create option on lookup fields on forms in lightning - if you have create permission on the lookup item.
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TvUBQA0

[image: This quick picture shows which settings drives the quick create functionality]

Are you sure that you have checked the OWD permissions on the object?
The answer above mine reflects correctly on your question, you cannot use this feature over multiple dialog/relations per 1 item creation. Try to use some kind of guided flow to achive your real needs.

Comment: I'm able to create a new Account, when i'm creating a new Contact from the Contacts tab, but when i'm creating a Contact from the Contact Lookup field which is on Lead, i'm not able to create a new Account ... i have to choose from the existing Accounts

Comment: @CyberJus is right, you cannot use quick create over multiple relations.

Answer (score 0):

You can only go one object away in creating a new record from a lookup field. You cannot create a new object, while creating a new object, while creating a new object.